# Why does specifying Exclusions change EvaluationMonitor behavior?

Tags: numerical-integration

Consider the following code:

```
evals = Last@
   Reap@NIntegrate[
     Log[(x - 0.45)^2 + (y - 0.3)^2], {x, 0, 1.3}, {y, Sin[3 x], 0}, 
     EvaluationMonitor :> Sow[{x, y}]
     (*, Exclusions\[Rule](x-0.45)^2+(y-0.3)^2\[Equal]0*)];
ListPlot[First@evals, PlotRange -> All, PlotStyle -> AbsolutePointSize[1], PlotTheme -> None]
```

[image: result without exclusions]

If I uncomment the `Exclusions` part, I get instead the following result:

[image: result with exclusions]

Seems now `EvaluationMonitor` gets somehow normalized coordinates instead of their true values. Why does it behave so? How can I work around/fix it?